# iPhone5 migration: black bar between tabbar and content view

Tags: ios6, iphone-5

I try to migrate an app to iPhone5/iOS6.
I have already successfully migrated some apps with basic recommandation (-568h@2x).

BUT for this app, a black bar appears between the bottom toolbar and the middle of the screen (Cf. attached image).

[image: black bar]

Normally, the black bar should be filled with the tableview...

Of course, I have correctly set the tableview constraint in Interface Builder...

Comment: Change the background color of the table view's superview, and see if that black color corresponds to that, it seems your view is not getting resize.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the pb... was not directly an iPhone5 issue but a bad usage of the new dimension from 1 component of my app... :(